# Como centralizar figure com max-width definido?

Tags: html5, css3

Estou tentando centralizar uma *figure* com `max-width` definido. Ao centralizar sem o `max-width`, da certo. Porém o *background* existe na mesma fica 100% e não centralizado junto a *figure*.
Para isso usei o `max-width`, porém ao usar a *figure* se alinha a esquerda novamente.
Existe algum outro jeito?

```
<figure id="img-home">
                <img src="img/col-1.jpg" alt="Cotação Individual, Familiar, Empresarial">
                <figcaption>
                    <strong>Cotação</strong>
                    <span><a href="#">Individual</a> | <a href="#">Familiar</a> | <a href="#">Empresarial</a></span>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>

#img-home {background: #eed46f; padding: 5px; max-width: 330px; text-align: center;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa adicionar `margin 0 auto;` na sua tag `figure`

```
#img-home {
    margin:0 auto;
    background: #eed46f; 
    padding: 5px; 
    max-width: 330px; 
    text-align: center;
}
```

Exemplo: **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8SUkJ/)**

Comment: Verdade, cara. Não sei como não pensei nisso antes. .-.
Valeu pela ajuda!